# Error on using Vim-latex ("can't find file ~")

Tags: vim, latex

I'm not sure if this question is appropriate here but I have nowhere else to ask. I recently started to typeset some 'mathsy' stuff using Latex and it became a hobby for me. I've been using TeXnicCenter for this, but feeling that I've got familiar with Latex language, I decieded to improve 'efficiency' of typesetting by changing the editor.

So I decided to use **Vim** (latest version, 7.4) with Suite-Latex. I've just installed Vim and Suite-Latex, following exactly what was instructed [here](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/index.php?subject=download&title=Download). I made every necessary changes mentioned [here](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/recommended-settings.html), and it seemed to me that installation was successful (I got what was expected on Step 4)

Then I started to work through [this tutorial](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite-quickstart/lsq-using-tutorial.html) and everything went fine until [this section](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite-quickstart/lsq-inserting-reference.html).

When I press  F9 for autoreference, I see that Vim is working on something for split seconds and red error message refering to "can't find [some file name]" in my user/appdata/local/temp directory. The "file name" changes every time I do this (so its kind of temporary file as its directory suggests?). And then it produces a new window with title **__ OUTLINE __** where 2 empty lines are showing up.

If I press n (in the new window described above) error message saying **"E486: Pattern not found: rf"** pops up and pressing j results in going down one row. If I press enter key, message **":call Tex_FinishOutlineCompletion()"** pops up.

More frustratingly, if I try to compile a file by entering command \ll, a new window pops up where there are two lines saying:

1.ll I can't find file `newfile.tex'. newfile.tex

2.ll Emergency stop

and below these is a message saying

**[Quickfix list]: latex -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error-style newfile.tex**

So I thought it maybe is something to do with VIM not being able to find files in my computer (so something wrong with grep?), and I tried to resolve it by downloading a software called "cygwin" on which developers said their tests were successful, but it changed nothing.

But I think the two problems are related.

As it is, I am completely newbie in this type of editing environment (or any kind of programming) but I really would like to learn some Vim seeing how efficient it is in typesetting etc. Sorry for not being a pro at typing codes here. Thanks for reading!

Comment: [This](https://github.com/vim-latex/vim-latex/issues) is the right place for your question.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need a latex compiler---I've had this issue and well, one thing that's left out of the conversation a lot is the compiler (pdflatex, latexmk, etc). As of now, you should download a compiler since vim-latex (latex-suite) doesn't actually come with a compiler (that I know of) and it's just a plug in with some cool stuff in it, but not what you need to make a file.pdf out of your file.tex.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me before. I found out that this problem may happen when you have special characters (such as white space and other symbols) in your file name or folder path. Try again with file name and path only in English letters.